# slider input overlaps header

Tags: html, css, header, slider

I have a div that contains a list, where each list item has a slider bar. Right above it is a fixed header, with full opacity. When I scroll down, everything is normal, except the slider bar can be seen fully above the header. The actual html aspect seems very simple and I couldn't find any issues with it, but I am assuming the problem is with the WebKit design, which I am not overly familiar with.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 60px;
}


/* List Elements */

.slidecontainer {
  display: block;
  color: #000;
  padding: 40% 5%;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 90%;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 75px;
  background: #e9e9e9;
  border-color: #e1e1e1;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px 0px;
}

header {
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #37393d;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}


/* SLIDER*/

.slider {
  margin: 8% 12.5%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 75%;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: #d3d3d3;
  outline: none;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #155724;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #4CAF50;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="sourcesContainer">
  <ul>
    <li class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider">
    </li>
    <li class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider">
    </li>
    <li class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider">
    </li>
    <li class="slidecontainer">
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" class="slider">
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please give us a clear picture?

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly, you have a white space above sliders.
That is `ul` margin, remove it `ul { margin-top: 0 }`